# Does Azure Connected Machine agent supports Ubuntu Core 16 OS

Tags: azure-connect, azure-arc

Want to install Azure Connected Machine agent on the machine where Ubuntu Core 16 OS is installed.
Is this supported??

Comment: Did you check the docs and the [supported OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/prerequisites) section?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Core is currently not supported.  See this link for a list of supported operating systems: [Azure Arc - Supported operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/prerequisites#supported-operating-systems)